# RMarkdown link to html local file

Tags: html, r, hyperlink

I would like to link to a local file. But it isn't working.

I use the following r code:

[Link] (../Marktaandeel/Project/index.html)

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It is an issue with the interpretation of ".." . The working directory when writing the markdown is not the same as when using the produced markdown file. Will it be possible for you to use absolute path instead of relative path? For example "file:://myhome/Marktaandeel/Project/index.html". IF so , you can find a more reliable way by storing the common part of the path to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Unfortunately it still isn't working. [Marktaandeel](file:://fscn01/Data/CFI/5.%20Staf/5.2%20Salesadviseur/Nieuwe%20structuur/Data%20analyses/Marktaandeel/Project/index.html)

Comment: sorry, my post had a typo. just use one : instead of two. It's merely the URI protocol, like http:// in the URL. Better look into an HTML reference like w3schools to make sure everything in your markdown is as you want it to be

Answer (score 1):

It's like trying to send .lnk file via mail. Won't work.